# Workflow to get multiple comments in Email

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have got a requirement to send emails to a team. Its like a ticketing system.
So when an item is created in a list, an email is sent to the whole team.
Then the team members can start commenting on the issue.
for ex:-

```
Comments
```

1. Issue submitted
2. work in progress
3. Port opening is required
4. Port opened.
5. Issue Closed

So for the first time the team gets an email that the

```
Comments
```

issue submitted

and second time when the email triggers then two comments should come in email.

```
 Comments
```

1. Issue submitted
2. work in progress

And so on..

So how can we manage these multiple comments by the team, can we do it with the same list where item adding triggers emails or do we need to create other list to maintain those comments.

Simply, what would be the way to show multiple comments related to a single item in email.

Answer (score 1):

[All about Collect Feedback workflows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Collect-Feedback-workflows-e0443930-6a88-4f71-ac4e-6ab591225066?CorrelationId=799a731b-cb0a-48c7-bb46-7de6de42ae17&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102615319)

- In the custom approval process, select 'Change the behaviour of a single task'
- Scroll down to the bottom step called 'When a task completes'
- Set an action where you save the task comments to a local variable. 'Set Variable:TaskComment to CurrentTask:Comments'
- Go back to the custom approval process, and select 'Change the behaviour of the overall task process'
- Scroll down to the bottom step called 'When the task process completes'
  Click on the Email:Workflow context:Initiator text
- Delete the part of the email containing the ConsolidatedComments variable, and insert the TaskComments variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to achieve the desired target :-)

A. If you are using SharePoint designer workflow 2010 follow these steps:

Step 1. Create two lists (single line of text), say List1 and List2.

Step 2: Let List1 be open for input on form and List2 is to be hidden.

Step 3: Append all the value updates of List1 in List2 (custom code). Use List2 in designer worklflow while emailing(hoping you are well ware how to use workflow designer).

B. If you are using SharePoint designer workflow 2013 follow the URLs

https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

Towards answering this question help me on a querie:
Can we provide dropdown, with all the mentioned commwets for the tickets?

Comment: No, comments are entered by the user